# scoring DNA script file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, bioinformatics

I want to score DNA sequence

```
A = 1 T = 2 C = 3 G = 4
```

---

My input is

```
ATGGCGATTGA  
AGCTTAGCCAG  
AGCTTAGGGAA
```

---

My output should be

```
seq_number 1 has score = 28  
seq_number 2 has score = 28  
seq_number 3 has score = 27
```

---

edited my input is .txt file

Comment: please add code you've tried as well... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask... `Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!`

Comment: Now that you're up to 6 un-accepted questions, consider letting this community know if the answers have solved your problem(s) by clicking the checkmarks on the answers.

Comment: Ahh! I see you haven't hit our [tour page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) yet -- earn a badge and learn more about how our site works!

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -e 's/A/./g'   -e 's/T/../g' \
    -e 's/C/.../g' -e 's/G/..../g' file |
awk '{ printf("seq_number %d has score = %d\n", NR, length) }'
```

Output:

```
seq_number 1 has score = 28
seq_number 2 has score = 28
seq_number 3 has score = 27
```

The `sed` command replaces each base by a number of dots that represents the score.  The `awk` command prints the number of lines read so far and also calculates the length of the line, which is the total score for that line.

The first `sed` expression, `s/A/./g`, in not actually needed for the result to be correct.

---

Variation (tiny bit shorter, just for fun):

```
sed -e 's/G/TT/g;s/C/TA/g;s/T/AA/g' file |
awk '{ printf("seq_number %d has score = %d\n", NR, length) }'
```

---

Variation that gives only the scores, one per line:

```
tr 'ATCG' '1234' <file | awk -F'\0' -vOFS="+" '$1=$1' | bc
```

This first replaces each letter with the digit that is the score for that letter, and then, with `awk`, inserts `+` between each digit.  The calculation of the total score for each line is then handled by `bc`.

And finally, a variation of the last one but with only `sed` and `bc` (again, only the scores are printed):

```
sed 'y/ATCG/1234/;s/\(.\)/+\1/g;s/^+//' file | bc
```

---

Sundeep came up with

```
sed 'y/ATCG/1234/;s/./+&/2g' file | bc
```

which is a shorter variation of my last thing.

It first changes the letters to the corresponding digits with the `y` command, and then replaces each character (from the second one onwards) with itself prepended by `+`, so for the input string `ACCA` you'll get `1+3+3+1` as output.  `bc` is then used to evaluate this arithmetic expression.

His solution works only in GNU `sed` as standard `sed` does not like getting both `2` and `g` as substitution flags at the same time.

Comment: using length rather than arithmetic is a nice idea.  The sed+awk one-liners can also be done entirely in awk using `gsub` - e.g. `awk '{ gsub(/A/,"."); gsub(/T/,".."); gsub(/C/,"..."); gsub(/G/,"....");
       printf("seq_number %d has score = %d\n", NR, length) }' input.txt`

Comment: last one golfed for GNU-sed .... `sed 'y/ATCG/1234/;s/./+&/2g' file | bc`

Comment: @Sundeep Nicely! You win!  :-)

Comment: same in perl: `perl -lne 'y/ATCG/1234/; s/./+$&/g; print "seq_number $. has score = " . eval $_;' input`

Comment: Also, the GNU `sed` version can be made to work in any `sed` by using just `/g` instead of `/2g` AND adding `;s/^/0/` so that the lines piped into `bc` start with `0+` rather than just `+`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple awk script could do it:

### score.awk

```
BEGIN {
  values["A"]=1
  values["T"]=2
  values["C"]=3
  values["G"]=4
}

{
  split($0, letters, "");
  sum=0;
  for (letter in letters)
    sum += values[letters[letter]];
    print "seq_number", NR, "has score =", sum;
}
```

When run on your sample data, I get:

```
$ awk -f score.awk < input
seq_number 1 has score = 28
seq_number 2 has score = 28
seq_number 3 has score = 27
```

Answer (score 1):

well, since this question is getting answered anyway, here's some `perl/ruby` one-liners

```
$ perl -MList::Util=sum0 -lne 'print "seq_number $. has score = ", sum0 split //, tr/ATCG/1234/r' ip.txt
seq_number 1 has score = 28
seq_number 2 has score = 28
seq_number 3 has score = 27
$ ruby -ne 'puts "seq_number #{$.} has score = #{$_.tr("ATCG", "1234").chars.sum(&:to_i)}"' ip.txt
seq_number 1 has score = 28
seq_number 2 has score = 28
seq_number 3 has score = 27
```

The idea is same, and applicable as long as letters translate to single digit number

- so, first use `tr` to change `ATCG` to corresponding `1234`
- then split the string on characters, and sum the digits

And an `awk` version using return value of `split`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a["A"]=1; a["T"]=2; a["C"]=3; a["G"]=4}
       {score = 0; for(k in a) score += (split($0, n, k)-1)*a[k];
        print "seq_number " NR " has score = " score}' ip.txt
seq_number 1 has score = 28
seq_number 2 has score = 28
seq_number 3 has score = 27
```